# Read XML file and return attribute value

Tags: c#, xml

I want to send AB as parameter and retrieve eds2.

XML File: Profile.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProfileCollection>
<Profiles>
    <Profile LibId="CD" ProfileId="ed1"/>
    <Profile LibId="AB" ProfileId="ed2"/>
</Profiles>
</ProfileCollection>
```

Tried options like below but no luck. foo is returning nothing. Note sure, what's missing.

```
public class Profile
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("LibId")]
    public string LibId { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("ProfileId")]
    public string ProfileId { get; set; }
}



[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("ProfileCollection")]
public class ProfileCollection
{
    [XmlArray("Profiles")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Profile", typeof(Profile))]
    public Profile[] Profile { get; set; }
}

public class XMLFile
{
    public String LibId;
    public String ProfileId;
}

public static String ReadXML(String libID)
{

    var foo = "";
    var xml = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Projects\OneSearch\XML\Profiles.xml");

    foo = (from n in xml.Descendants("Profiles")
           where n.Element("Profile").Attribute("LibId").Value  == libraryID
           select n.Element("Profile").Attribute("ProfileId").Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

Any advise asap pls? Tks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear whether you're trying to use XML serialization or not - you've got serialization attributes, but then you're not using an XML serializer... you should decide one way or another.

Comment: Your LINQ to XML code isn't ideal, but it does actually work-  if `libraryID` is `CD` then I get `foo` set to `ed1`.  So what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from xml serialization attributes in your code (are you really using it?), your code concerning retrieving ProfileId could look like:

```
foo = (from n in xml.XPathSelectElements("ProfileCollection/Profiles/Profile")
       where n.Attribute("LibId").Value == libraryID
       select n.Attribute("ProfileId").Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I tried but no longer using xml serialization attributes anymore.

Comment: for the advised code, XDocument does not have a method called XPathSelectElements?

Comment: @Dips it is extension method. Make sure you're included `using System.Xml.XPath;` in your code.

Comment: @Dips You are welcome. Consider [marking answer as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) just instead of "thank you" if answer was helpful. It will also help others having similar question to find correct answer.